# Deleting ONE record with Sequelize

Tags: typescript, postgresql, sequelize.js

Using `destroy`, I can delete ALL records that fit the `where` clause, but it doesn't seem to play well with `limit`.

```
await TableName.destroy({
    where : { name: 'FooBar' }
})
```

What modifier can I use to limit the deleted rows? Or preferably delete the first row that matches the `where` clause?

Comment: You could fetch a single row and delete that instance. I couldn't find anything in the documentation about deleting only one row...

Comment: use a unique field to delete instead of a generic one. Think of it as sql. if you use a generic field, it'll delete all matches. You either use a unique key to delete, or use multiple fields to make the record match unique.

Comment: Thank you ! Using both of your comments I came up with a solution.